# single sign on across two servers

Tags: authentication, sso

I have been wondering how and what kind of tools are needed to do single sign on in the following scenario:

1) Alice is logged in to site X hosted by server W

2) Alice navigates site Y hosted by server Z

3) Alice uses her login credentials for site X to access site Y

How does the browser share the login information from the session with W to attempt to create a session with Z?

Does Z send login credentials to W and receive a response indicating success/failure?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for OpenID?

Answer (score 2):

This is called federated authentication.  In the enterprise world, this is often accomplished with [Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)) (for non-web based systems) or [SAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language) (for web-based systems.)

In the non-enterprise world, far and away the most popular federation framework is [OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).  There is an extension to OAuth 2 called [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/connect/) (much different from the older OpenID Authentication protocol) that is specifically geared at authentication and profile sharing.

Comment: Xander this has been a great help. It seems though that people tend to mix sso with federated authentication, whilst they appear to be quite distinct? Is this so? Can SAML be used for both SSO and Federated?